# Adding attributes to attributed text in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I tried to add attributes to a text label:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

let para = NSMutableAttributedString()
let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "DIN Alternate", size: 18.0)
let font2:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12.0)
let labelColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
let text="some text"

//A, error appears here
let myAttributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle,
                    NSFontAttributeName:font,
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:labelColor]

let attrString = NSAttributedString(
    string: csvObject.provideDetailsAsString(poi)!,
    attributes: myAttributes)
para.appendAttributedString(attrString)     
detailsText.attributedText = para
```

But Swift compiler errors in line //A and says:

```
'_' is not convertible to 'String'
```

**I am using XCode 6.4 and Swift 1.2**

Answer (score 1):

Found it, add a ! after **font** : NSFontAttributeName:font!

**font** is **optional**